# JavaScript arrays - adding values across keys with exceptions

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, addition

I am trying to take all entries in an array and combine them into one single array.

Here is an example:

```
x = "x"
var oldArray = [
    [2,2,1,2,2,x,2,2,2,x,2,2,1],
    [1,2,x,2,2,x,2,1,2,x,2,2,x]
];
```

What I am trying to achieve is a new array which looks like this:

```
var newArray = 
    [3,4,x,4,4,x,4,3,4,x,4,4,x];
```

The character *x* is like a flag to ignore the addition. If there is an *x* in either value then the new value will simply be *x*.

Each sub-array will always have the same length, however there may more than two sub-arrays.

Comment: How many subArrays there could be in `oldArray`? Just 2 or many?

Comment: Multiple at the moment there are 40 keys, each with 63 values - this wont change.

Comment: Please see the results of running [this test](https://jsperf.com/reductionwithforeach/1), comparing the code in the accepted answer to the code in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
x = "x"
var oldArray = [
  [2, 2, 1, 2, 2, x, 2, 2, 2, x, 2, 2, 1],
  [1, 2, x, 2, 2, x, 2, 1, 2, x, 2, 2, x]
];

var result = oldArray.reduce(function(res, sub) { // for each sub
  for(var i = 0; i < sub.length; i++) { // for each item in sub
    if(sub[i] == x) res[i] = x; // if this item sub[i] is x then make res[i] == x 
    else if(res[i] != x) res[i] = (res[i] || 0) + sub[i]; // if not and if res[i] is not already set to x then add sub[i] to res[i] and store it back into res[i] (if res[i] is not yet defined add 0 instead)
  }
  return res; // return the accumulator (see the docs for Array.prototype.reduce)
}, []); // start with an empty array as the accumulator res (see the docs)

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [array.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to return an array of the added values, iterating over each sub-array and returning the resulting array (the *accumulator* argument). Inside the callback to passed to *reduce()*, use [array.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/foreach) to iterate over each element in the sub-array.

```
var newArray = oldArray.reduce(function(accumulator, subArray, subArrayIndex) {
    //process each sub-array
    subArray.forEach(function(value, index) {
        //process each element in the sub-array
    });
    //return accumulator after processing the sub-array (at subArrayIndex)
}, []);
```

This technique has advantages over the accepted answer, including not having to worry about incrementing the iterator index manually, limiting the looping condition (e.g. `for(var j=0; j < array.length; j++)` ), etc. For more reading about advantages of functional techniques with reduce(), map(), etc. see [functional programming in JavaScript](http://reactivex.io/learnrx). I recommend the exercises.

```js
x = "x"
var oldArray = [
  [2, 2, 1, 2, 2, x, 2, 2, 2, x, 2, 2, 1],
  [1, 2, x, 2, 2, x, 2, 1, 2, x, 2, 2, x]
];
var newArray = oldArray.reduce(function(accumulator, subArray, subArrayIndex) {
  subArray.forEach(function(value, index) {
    if (value == x) {
      accumulator[index] = x; //make newArray[index] an x
    } else if (accumulator[index] !== x) { //don't add to an x
      accumulator[index] = value + (accumulator[index] ? accumulator[index] : 0); //add the value from the current sub-array
    }
  });
  return accumulator;
}, []); //the array (2nd argument) is the initial value for the accumulator
console.log('newArray: ', newArray);
```

#### Edit:

Based on [this test](https://jsperf.com/reductionwithforeach/1) on [jsperf.com](http://jsperf.com), the snippet in this answer is **faster** than the accepted answer.

Comment: This won't handle the case it `oldArray` contain more than two sub arrays! See the comments of the question!

Comment: Darn I thought he said just two earlier... will revise

Answer (score 0):

Pretty simple. This works for any number of things in both dimensions.

```
x = "x"
var oldArray = [
    [2,2,1,2,2,x,2,2,2,x,2,2,1],
    [1,2,x,2,2,x,2,1,2,x,2,2,x]
];
newArray = []
for(i=0;i<oldArray.length;i++){
    for(j=0;j<oldArray[i].length;j++){
        if(oldArray[i][j] == x || newArray[j] == x)
            newArray[j] = x;
        else{
            if( i == 0 )
                newArray[j] = oldArray[i][j];
            else
                newArray += oldArray[i][j];            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In your solution the loop continues and update the new array even if the value "x" was already found ... in the case of 40 lines it will be a loss of performance.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this like that :

```
var x = "x"
var max_x = max_y = 0;
var newArray = [];
var oval = nval = null;

var oldArray = [
    [2,2,1,2,2,x,2,2,2,x,2,2,1],
    [1,2,x,2,2,x,2,1,2,x,2,2,x]
];

max_x = oldArray[0].length;
max_y = oldArray.length;

for(var n1= 0; n1<max_x; n1++) {
  nval = 0;
  for(var n0=0; n0<max_y; n0++) {
    oval = oldArray[n0][n1];
      if(oval === x) {
        nval = oval;
        break;
       }
    nval += oval;
  }
  newArray.push(nval);
}

console.log(newArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use nested `for..of` loop, `Array.prototype.entries()`

```js
const x = "x";

let oldArray = [
    [2,2,1,2,2,x,2,2,2,x,2,2,1],
    [1,2,x,2,2,x,2,1,2,x,2,2,x]
];

let res = [];

for (let arr of oldArray) {
  for (let [key,  value] of arr.entries()) {
    if (res[key] !== x) res[key] = value === x ? x : (res[key] || 0) + value;
  }
}

console.log(res);
```

Comment: Browser compatibility with [let](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let#Browser_compatibility) may be an issue for some developers who need to support a wide range of browsers used by customers...

Answer (score 0):

Blahh Blahh i found the simplest solution :)

```
<html>

    <script>
    x = "x";
    var oldArray = [
        [2,2,1,2,2,x,2,2,2,x,2,2,1],
        [1,2,x,2,2,x,2,1,2,x,2,2,x]
    ];
    var newArray = [];

    var u ;
    var length = oldArray[0].length;

    for(var i = 0 ; i< length  ; i++ )

    {
    alert(oldArray[0][i]+" "+oldArray[1][i]);
        if(oldArray[0][i]!= x &&  oldArray[1][i] != x){
            u = oldArray[0][i]+oldArray[1][i];
            newArray.push(u);
            }
            else if(oldArray[0][i]== x){
            newArray.push(x);
            }
            else if (oldArray[1][i] == x) {
            newArray.push(x);
            }

    }
    console.log(newArray);
    </script>
```

Comment: Don't use alert to log the values ... And your proposition work only if you have 2 rows in oldArray. @Matt search a solution for "n" rows. Next time, readed correctly the ask and precisions in the commentaries :)

Comment: its just for the testing purpose sorry for that :) http://stackoverflow.com/users/4128485/thibault-bach